# Create Java Project in Eclipse from SVN Repository Containing Several Languages

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant

I've found similar questions to this problem but they don't really satisfy my situation.  My code is apart of a single "project" in an SVN repository.  The "project" includes not just Java code, but also C/C++/Cuda.  I simply want to check the entire repository out but *only* work on the Java code (that runs from an Ant build).

I'm looking for a way in Eclipse (using Subclipse) to have this code as a Java project, while "ignoring" the other stuff.

I edited the ".project" file to recognize it as a Java project, but only the `<natures>` tag and not `<buildSpec>`, since the Java code is compiled from an Ant build.  This works to a degree but Content Assist doesn't work.

The code layout in the repository is something like this:

```
root/  
    backend/ (C++/CUDA)  
    frontend/ (Java here)
    jar/ (runnable jar is here)
    build.xml
```

Comment: What is the folder structure like in svn? Are all the java files mixed in the same directory as c/c++/Cuda code?

Comment: Made an edit to show the general folder structure.

Comment: I suggest to check out the root dir entirely(because you really want this as you said) as a general eclipse project. Then create a new java project and set the source directory to the root/frontend and include build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a .project and .classpath file to the frontend folder and "import" it as a java project.  It will show up as another project in the workspace and you'll have full java features.

Comment: Great, this does precisely what I want.  Thanks!